# Binary management/delivery

Tags: windows-server-2003, content-management

Is there any good solution to management server application binaries (may up to 1GB), with the aim of achieving version control and delivery, and have a way to verify that every remote server has same version?

To be more specific, usually we have to unzip and deploy serverA.zip (which may contains some exe/dll/configuration) to some server group, serverB.zip to some other server group. Except using script to copy file over, is there any other more reliable way?

Our operating system is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same installation package to install the application on each server?